# Can PyTorch GPU Use Shared GPU Memory (from RAM, shows in Windows Task Manage)?

Tags: windows, pytorch, shared-gpu-memory

Someone says that it can use, who verified it by running chatglm6b model on Windows with 1660s (6g). He claimed that it can't run under linux but he didn't test it. I don't use PyTorch. My CUDA experience told me that Nvidia doesn't take shared GPU memory. So it's either some magic created by Windows or both PyTorch and the Task Manager provided some wrong information.
Can someone explain how could this work? Isn't it downgraded to CPU for slower processing?

Sample Code:

```
import torch
a=torch.nn.Linear(128,256)
a=a.to('cuda')
b=torch.rand((20000000,128))
b=b.to('cuda')
c=a.forward(b)
```

Dedicated GPU Memory shows 11.7/12GB on a 3080Ti, Shared GPU Memory shows 18.3GB/32GB.

Comment: similar experience here - running latest whisper --device cuda --model large-v2 results in out of memory error on Linux (3070 8Gb), all the while the same whisper version with the same params and the same hardware works on WSL. i didn't compare performance though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Windows 10 and 11 and newer operating systems, Microsoft introduced GPU shared memory, which uses 50% of physical memory for uniform addressing by default.
For CUDA, if you use Nvidia driver version 536 and newer versions under the above operating systems, then you can indeed use shared memory when you are low on memory. (This also applies to wsl). This behavior is not demoted to the CPU, but it can still significantly slow things down. This is because the actual operation passes through the PCIE bus and accesses the DDR memory. Here are my tests with win11 23H2 and chatglm3(PCIE3). You can see the Copy and individual memory usage.
[demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzfBF.png)

Comment: It's interesting that my 3090 with Win11 has this feature, my 1070 also has this feature, but my Quadro P4000 (same generation of 1070) doesn't allow this.